# Symfony2: exception upon persisting onetomany-manytoone entities

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building an entry form in which a file submission form in embedded. The two entities are related by a bidirectional relation like so:

```
class Entry
{
     /**
      *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OOTN\BlogBundle\Entity\Image", mappedBy="Entry", cascade={"persist"})
      *@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
      */
      private $image;

      //rest of Entry class

class Image
{
    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OOTN\BlogBundle\Entity\Entry", cascade={"persist"})
     *@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    */
    private $entry;

    //attributes id, date, url and alt here

    private $file;


    public function upload()
    {
         if (null === $this->file)
         {
             return;
         }
         $name = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();

         $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $name);
         $this->url = $name;
         $this->alt = $name;
    }

    //functions getUploadDir and getUploadRootDir here
```

The forms are embedded fine but upon persisting the entry, I get a sql error telling me that the entry_id for Image is null. I thought symfony would take care of that itself but I nonetheless tried to set it by hand in the controller with something like this:

```
    $entry->getImage()->setEntry($entry);
```

When I do this, not only is entry_id null, but url and alt as well. As if upload() wasn't doing its job (and yet it does, 'cause the files are indeed uploaded). I can't really figure it out, someone knows what's going on?

Comment: Could you also try adding the addImage method in the Entry class and do:
1. Add the image to the entry
2. set the entry from the image

I guess there is a bidirectional issue to find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Ninir's comment. You indeed need an addImage method in the entry class, plus a constructor that looks like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->image = new ArrayCollection(); 
    //don't forget a "use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;" statement
}
```

In your controller, do something like this:

```
$listImages = $entry->getImage();

foreach($listImages as $image)
{
    $entry->addImage($image);
    $image->setEntry($entry);
    $image->upload();
}
```

It did the trick for me.